# can't find mingw directory xmake

Tags: lua, xmake

I'm new to `xmake`, I've wrote a `xmake.lua` but when I try to execute `xmake` I receive the following issue:

```sh
checking for platform ... mingw
checking for architecture ... x86_64
checking for mingw directory ... no
please run:
    - xmake config --mingw=xxx
or  - xmake global --mingw=xxx
```

I tried to make the `xmake config` command by specifying the path of the mingw exe but still the same error.

Comment: which OS are you building from, and are you cross-compiling for a different system

Comment: @Doyousketch2 I'm on windows but I would like xmake to compile for mac and linux/fedora too because it's a group project with people on different os

Comment: I wonder if it's a forward-slash  /  vs escaped-backslash  \\  issue.  which are you using for directory seperators?

Comment: where is your mingw directory? you can try `xmake f --mingw=your_mingw_rootdir -c` or add mingw bin path to %PATH% and xmake will detect it.